# JavaFx with NetBeans and Ubuntu?

Tags: javafx-2

I'm looking for a how to use JavaFX-2 with NetBeans and Ubuntu. I have JDK8 installed and now I'm looking for JavaFX SDK to Linux and still haven't found that's it. Looking for in Oracle web site I didn't found also.

JavaFX SDK to Linux not exist ?

Comment: [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/install-javafx-sdk-1-2-139156.html#3) Take a look here the last 3/4 of the page have info on linux. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Java 8 installed, then JavaFX 8 is the component of intallation by default.
Just start development in Netbeans. 
JavaFX works in linux ubuntu well. 
Netbeans is a usefull IDE for development in such case.